# Какой конкретно язык обсуждают в этом разделе СЕ? Где русский язык в данной фразе?

Tags: discussion

Я столкнулся с непониманием того, какой именно язык обсуждается в этом разделе СЕ.

Особенно ярко это было проявлено в вопросе о фразе, которая не мыслится хоть сколько-нибудь корректной и грамотной в пространстве русского языка. Вот так это звучало:

[**Лошадь, которая плохо везёт, нужно бить.**](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/26907/is-the-sentence-%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-grammatically-correct)

Под русским языком я понимаю язык Пушкина, Гоголя, Достоевского, Толстого, Блока, Есенина, Маяковского и многих других творцов русского языка и его главного Творца - русского народа, их пословиц и поговорок, которые записывал всем известный исследователь языка и филолог Даль. Под русским народом и русскими писателями я понимаю не национальность, Даль, как всем известно, был датчанином...

Так вот, но где они, границы русского языка и русской речи? То есть в математике - есть законы в виде аксиом, есть правило, запрещающее деление на нОль. В физике - это законы сохранения энергии, например. А где границы, законы языка? Ну а ежели науки о языке - филология и лингвистика, - гуманитарные, то где-то должны быть границы человечности? По крайней мере в русском языке она очевидна.

Вот есть фраза: "Лошадь, которая плохо везёт, нужно бить". В моём понимании, эта фраза не грамотна по целому ряду критериев согласованности, в том числе и из-за одушевленности, но главное, это образ, который не мыслится в рамках русского языка и русской культуры, неотрывно с ним связанной, ну кроме того что она оскорбительна.

Я начинаю размышлять, вспоминая и занимаясь поиском источников которые могли бы подтвердить или опровергнуть моё ощущение.

Вот что вспоминаю и нахожу:

> Добрую лошадь одной рукой бей, другою слезы вытирай.
>
> Лошади чужие, хомут не свой — погоняй, не стой.
>
> Конь не пахарь, не кузнец, не плотник, а первый на селе работник.
>
> На кнуте далеко не уедешь.

И прочие пословицы и поговорки... а вот из литературы, думаю, всем же знакомо ещё со школы и не составит труда узнать авторов?

> *Били копыта, Пели будто: - Гриб. Грабь. Гроб. Груб.- Ветром опита, льдом обута улица скользила. Лошадь на круп грохнулась.за зевакой зевака, штаны пришедшие Кузнецким клёшить, сгрудились, смех зазвенел и зазвякал: - Лошадь упала! - Упала лошадь! - Смеялся Кузнецкий. Лишь один я голос свой не вмешивал в вой ему. Подошел и вижу глаза лошадиные...*

> *— Добивай! — кричит Миколка и вскакивает, словно себя не помня, с телеги. Несколько парней, тоже красных и пьяных, схватывают что попало — кнуты, палки, оглоблю, и бегут к издыхающей кобыленке. Миколка становится сбоку и начинает бить ломом зря по спине. Кляча протягивает морду, тяжело вздыхает и умирает. — Доконал! — кричат в толпе. — А зачем вскачь не шла! — Мое добро! — кричит Миколка, с ломом в руках и с налитыми кровью глазами. Он стоит будто жалея, что уж некого больше бить.*

> Зима!.. Крестьянин, торжествуя, На дровнях обновляет путь; Его лошадка, снег почуя, Плетется рысью как-нибудь; Бразды пушистые
> взрывая, Летит кибитка удалая; Ямщик сидит на облучке В тулупе, в
> красном кушаке. Вот бегает дворовый мальчик, В салазки жучку посадив,
> **Себя в коня преобразив**; Шалун уж заморозил пальчик: Ему и больно и
> смешно, А мать грозит ему в окно...

> *Эх, тройка! птица тройка, кто тебя выдумал? знать, у бойкого народа ты могла только родиться, в той земле, что не любит шутить, а ровнем-гладнем разметнулась на полсвета, да и ступай считать версты, пока не зарябит тебе в очи. И не хитрый, кажись, дорожный снаряд, не железным схвачен винтом, а наскоро живьем с одним топором да долотом снарядил и собрал тебя ярославский расторопный мужик. Не в немецких ботфортах ямщик: борода да рукавицы, и сидит черт знает на чем; а привстал, да замахнулся, да затянул песню — кони вихрем, спицы в колесах смешались в один гладкий круг, только дрогнула дорога, да вскрикнул в испуге остановившийся пешеход — и вон она понеслась, понеслась, понеслась!.. И вон уже видно вдали, как что-то пылит и сверлит воздух.*
>
> *Не так ли и ты, Русь, что бойкая необгонимая тройка несешься? Дымом дымится под тобою дорога, гремят мосты, все отстает и остается позади. Остановился пораженный Божьим чудом созерцатель: не молния ли это, сброшенная с неба? что значит это наводящее ужас движение? и что за неведомая сила заключена в сих неведомых светом конях? Эх, кони, кони, что за кони! Вихри ли сидят в ваших гривах? Чуткое ли ухо горит во всякой вашей жилке? Заслышали с вышины знакомую песню, дружно и разом напрягли медные груди и, почти не тронув копытами земли, превратились в одни вытянутые линии, летящие по воздуху, и мчится вся вдохновенная Богом!.. Русь, куда ж несешься ты? дай ответ. Не дает ответа. Чудным звоном заливается колокольчик; гремит и становится ветром разорванный в куски воздух; летит мимо все, что ни есть на земле, и, косясь, постораниваются и дают ей дорогу другие народы и государства...*

Однако, мои замечания о связи языка с его авторами и творцами были встречены с непониманием. Причем, это непонимание я встречаю не только у мимопроходящих пользователей, но даже у модераторов данного раздела.

Так вот, мой вопрос: какой язык тут обсуждают, это действительно русский язык? и может ли язык мыслиться вне его автора, как автономная обособленная система заков и символов, будет ли это тот же язык или какой-то другой?

То есть когда на твоём родном языке говорит иностранец, а не русский. "Не русский" не в плане национальности, а в плане native speaking - это же становится понятно, после пары фраз, что это не русская речь, а какая-то другая, человек переводит свою речь, звучащую на другой языке на слова из, вроде бы, русского языка, но фраз не выглядят грамотными и любому русскоговорящему это ясно как божий день.

Так где эта граница понимания и чувства языка, есть ли она? или я ошибаюсь, а если так, то в чём моя ошибка?

P.s: и еще замечу, что такой пропасти непонимания связи языка с его автором и слова с образом не возникает в разделе ["Русский язык СЕ"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), но только тут, где Russian language.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147997/discussion-on-question-by--------); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

> Я столкнулся с непониманием того, какой именно язык обсуждается в этом разделе СЕ.

This is not a discussion site; it's a question and answer site — there's a difference. We ask questions and provide answers about the Russian language on here.

I'm sure you know this, but since you're asking this question, I'll clarify it: the Russian language is an East Slavic language, the official language of the Russian Federation and Belarus, and also widely spoken in Ukraine, Kazakhstan, Moldova, other countries in Central Asia and Eastern Europe, and by numerous communities around the world.

> Вот есть фраза: "Лошадь, которая плохо везёт, нужно бить". В моём понимании, эта фраза не грамотна по целому ряду критериев согласованности, в том числе и из-за одушевленности, но главное, это образ, который не мыслится в рамках русского языка и русской культуры, неотрывно с ним связанной, ну кроме того что она оскорбительна.

You have posted an answer to that effect. As I write this, your answer has one upvote and three downvotes (including mine). This means that at least one member of the community has deemed your answer useful, and at least three other members have deemed it not useful.

> Однако, мои замечания о связи языка с его авторами и творцами были встречены с непониманием. Причем, это непонимание я встречаю не только у мимопроходящих пользователей, но даже у модераторов данного раздела.

It happens. That's how the mechanics of this site work.

I'll reiterate that it's not a discussion site; it's a question and answer site.

The original poster has asked [a very precise question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/26907/is-the-sentence-%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-grammatically-correct) about the grammatical correctness of a certain phrase. In my opinion, you gave an absolutely wrong answer to that question in the first couple of sentences (mixing grammatical correctness with moral rectitude). The rest of your answer seemed to me as pointless musings.

I don't think it's a useful answer. I believe that it's wrong, poorly written, and digresses from the question that was asked. I expressed this personal opinion by casting a downvote on it.

The majority of the members of the community who have elected to express their opinions through the voting system, found your answer not useful as well.

> Так вот, мой вопрос: какой язык тут обсуждают, это действительно русский язык?

For the third time, I'll write that this is not a discussion site. We ask and answer questions about the Russian language and its usage. I do that in English, other users in English and Russian alike. But yes, it's indeed about Russian.

> Так где эта граница понимания и чувства языка, есть ли она? или я ошибаюсь, а если так, то в чём моя ошибка?

I'll skip this part and the rest of its development because it's not about the site and hence off topic.

You are free to discuss this in the chat if you can find anyone interested in engaging in discussion about these matters with you (I'm not).

> P.s: и еще замечу, что такой пропасти непонимания связи языка с его автором и слова с образом не возникает в разделе "Русский язык СЕ", но только тут, где Russian language.

That is a different community with different audience, members and traditions.

If you feel that your contributions are better valued there than here, and that its members' linguistic sense is more aligned with yours than that of our members, it would seem natural for me that you might want to shift your efforts towards participation in that community.

However, until you start crossing lines in interpersonal communication or overburden moderators with other rules violations, you're welcome to participate here as well.

Comment: Так вы сами исправили тег вопроса на "дискуссия", и сами начинаете себе же противоречить. То что сайт "не дискуссионный" не значит, что обсуждение запрещено. Мне стоит учитывать тот факт, что вы отвечаете по-английски, а не по-русски, хотя русским вы также владеете? Также я не очень понимаю пользу вашего ответа, ввиду того, что ответа на поставленный вопрос в нём нет, а есть только сторонние и противоречивые рассуждения о теге, который вы же туда и добавили?

Comment: However, until you start crossing lines.. - именно так, где границы связанные с языком и вопросами о языке и переход в другие области? именно этот вопрос я и задал, однако, вы не отвечаете на него и ссылаетесь на некие границы. Так где эти самые границы, о которых вы пишите?

Comment: @άνθρωπος: calling the users names, using harsh language etc. You cannot do this here and continue participating.

Comment: Каким образом вы судите о том, обзываю я или еще что? Если в вашем понимании язык - это просто набор символов. Просто строчки в чате. В каком месте я кого-то обзывал, где? Я такого не припомню и я не знаю вашего имени, чтобы вас обзывать, я даже не уверен вы человек или нейросеть. Если вы говорите, что язык - это набор симулякров, находящихся в логических отношениях, то тогда о каком обзывательства может идти речь, если это вы сами присвоили оскорбительное значение какому-то слову и сами обиделись? Есть поговорка из анекдота(персонажи евреи говорят): вы или трусы наденьте, или крестик снимите.

Comment: @άνθρωπος: I'm using my best judgement to deem the language as harsh or not. If I consider that it is, I will make sure that it stops. You can read more about our moderation policies in our [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Я не понимаю, о чем вы говорите. Это вопрос или утверждение? Вы хотите меня спросить оскорбляю ли  я вас или кого-то? нет, у меня нет цели кого-то оскорбить, но я не могу отвечать за то, что вам кажется или нет значат те слова или фразы которые я пишу. И хотя это, скорее всего, важно обсудить, но вопрос не касался оскорблений или оскорблений персоналий, так что я не понимаю как это связано с тем о чем задан вопрос? То есть вы сейчас меня втягиваете в дискуссию, одновременно говоря, что дискутировать запрещено и в случае чего вы примените санкции модератора?

Comment: Так что мне делать? отвечать вам объясняя мою позицию или просто игнорировать, потому что любые обсуждения запрещены и любые мои слова могут быть расценены как оскорбление и направлены против меня же?

Comment: @άνθρωπος: I'm not interested in any discussions with you. I answered your question: _Каким образом вы судите о том, обзываю я или еще что?_: I use my best judgement.

Comment: и еще я не понимаю, зачем писать вот такие оправдания " I'm not interested in any discussions with you." при этом явно отвечая и комментируя, в очередной раз опровергая словами свои же действия, абсолютно не логично, но:  if "I use my best judgement" - i hope, you do so, my hope dies last.

Comment: @Cocopop: any reason you added "and" before "also"? To me, it reads "Russian is an X and also spoken in Y": is it how it works in English or am I missing something?

Comment: @Quassnoi: The sentence isn't balanced without it. It's like only writing **также** where you need **а также**.

Comment: @CocoPop: shouldn't it be "and is also spoken in"? I can't shake the feeling something is off with this sentence

Comment: @Quassnoi: You're right, but the *is* is there. It's just covert. Think of it this way: The Russian language **is** an East Slavic language, **(is)** the official language of the Russian Federation and Belarus, and **(is)** also widely spoken in Ukraine, Kazakhstan, Moldova, other countries in Central Asia and Eastern Europe, and by numerous communities around the world.